# ggplot: line with different widths

Tags: r, ggplot2

With ggplot2, it is really easy to plot a line with two colours, based on the value of the "col" variable, but is it possible to plot a line with the left part with one width and the right part with another one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different width for the lines if you use the `size=` argument inside the `aes()` and set it to variable that divides your data.

The look of the plot will depend on variable that divides your data in groups.

If the variable is factors then you will get gap between parts of lines.

```
df1<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
ggplot(df1,aes(x,y,size=z))+geom_line()
```

[image]

If the variable is numeric then there will be no gap.

```
df2<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4))
ggplot(df2,aes(x,y,size=z))+geom_line()
```

[image]